# PostgreSQL - on conflict update for GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of values which I want to manage with my application ...

let's say this is the table

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    id_student int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    id_teacher int2
    student_name varchar(255),
    age int2
    CONSTRAINT provider_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_student)
);
```

In the application, each teacher can see the list of all his/her students .. and they can edit or add new students

I am trying to figure out how to UPSERT data in the table in PostgreSQL ... what I am doing now is for each teacher (after the manipulation in the app) they are allowed to edit on FE only in JS (without the necessity of saving each change individually)... so after the edit, they click SAVE button and that's the time I need to store the changes and new records in the DB ...

what I do now, is I delete all records for that particular teacher and store the new object/array they created (by editing, adding, .. whatever) - so it's easy and I don't have to check for changes and new records ... the drawbacks is a brutal waste of the sequence for ID_STUDENT (autogenerated on the DB side) and of course a huge overhead on indexes while inserting (=rebuilding) considering there will be a lot of teachers saving a lot of their students .. that might cause some perf issues ... not to mention the fragmenting (HWM) so I would have to VACUUM regularly on this table

In Oracle, I could easily use MERGE INTO (which is fantastic for this use case) but the MERGE is not in the PostgreSQL :(

the only thing I know about is the INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE ... but the problem is, how am I supposed to apply this on GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY key? I do not provide this sequence (on top of that I don't even know the latest number) and therefore I cannot trigger the ON CONFLICT (id_student) ....

is there any nice way out of this sh*t ? Or DELETE / INSERT is really the way to go?

Comment: Surely your UI identifies existing students (with an id) and distinguishes them from new students? Treat them differently in your query as well. (And delete those that are no longer in the list).

Comment: yes of course.. bec whlie getting the existing list of students (on mounted() ) I pass the IDs as well .. and new records do not have them .. but this sort of process does not sound optimal to me at all :( there will be a lot of checking and lot of queries on the BE as well (INSERT,UPDATE, DELETE) ..  isn't there any way to handle it?

Comment: What do you mean by "*there will be a lot of checking and lot of queries on the BE*"? You could put all of this in a single sql statement if you wanted, but there's no problem with doing three queries or even one per row.

Comment: ` INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE` deals with all this. Just always use it when saving a record. If the record being saved has a `id_student that already exists the `UPDATE` part will run, otherwise the record will be `INSERTed`. `DELETE` will be a separate operation and will have the `id_student` already .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be too worried about the data churn – after all, an `UPDATE` also writes a new version of the row, so it wouldn't be that much different. And the sequence is no problem, because you used `bigint` for the primary key, right (anything else would have been a mistake)?

If you want to use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` in combination with an auto-generated sequence, you need some way beside the primary key to identify a row, that is, you need a `UNIQUE` constraint that you can use with `ON CONFLICT`. If there is no candidate for such a constraint, how can you identify the records for the teacher?

Comment: there is id_teacher (that binds the data to a particular teacher.. anyway: are you saying that the DELETE/INSERT is fine?

Comment: Yes. If there are a lot of unchanged rows that keep getting deleted and re-inserted, you might want to come up with something smarter. If there are only few rows affected (say, a couple of million per day), don't worry overly much. Set `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 2ms` and forget about it.

Comment: noted.. I don't expect more than a couple of million a day anytime soon .. thx for the tip with the `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay`  !!